# How to compare values of documents of diferents collections in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection that I want to search if any of the id of your documents matches a field of documents from another collection

Find the field value of the document of one collection with the value of the document of the other and if it exists, then create and update a field in the first collection

Comment: can you show the code that you tried? and by id you mean _id?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected result? the question seems pretty much incomplete without input and expected result.